# Connecting Salesforce and ExactTarget to Send Emails Through ExactTarget

Tags: api, integration

Is it possible when data changes in SFDC, to automatically (in real-time or near real time) do something in ExactTarget?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Salesforce can do callout to any external REST or SOAP-based API, and this can be setup from a trigger on a Salesforce record. ExactTarget also has data sync and integration built into its AppExchange app.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the response. So to narrow this down a little further, lets explore this scenario.

Comment: A checkbox field on a contact record gets checked from a workflow rule running in salesforce.com. When that happens, we need to send an email to that contact. that email is stored in and managed by exacttarget. is that still possible?

Comment: Yes, your workflow field update could fire a trigger, which does a callout to ET to send the email. It's a bunch of code to be sure but you asked if it was possible. I would just have my workflow send the email from Salesforce, which would be far easier.

Comment: thanks greenstork. the reason exacttarget is being used is to handle the volume of email sending, which far exceeds the limits of salesforce.com.

Comment: You're exceeding the daily workflow email limit of 1000 emails per user and a max of 2,000,000?

Comment: yes. it would be a very large volume of emails